# Jasmine spyOn mongoose save

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jasmine

I'd like to mock the save() function of a Mongoose model. The function I want to test looks like this in a file called user.js:

```
var User = import('User.js')

post: function(req, res) {
  var user = new User({
      password    : req.body.password,
      email       : req.body.email,
  });
  user.save( function(err) {
    if (err) {
      ....
    } else {
      ....
    }
  });
```

I tried to write a test that looks like this in another file called user_spec.js:

```
var Hander = require('user.js')

it('works properly', function() {
  spyOn(User, 'save').andReturn(null)
  Handler.post(req, res);
});
```

but that gives me the error:

```
save() method does not exist
```

I've done some more digging and it looks like the User model itself does not have the save() method, an instance does. This would mean I have to mock the constructor of User, but I'm having a lot of trouble with this. Other posts refer to a statement like:

```
spyOn(window, User)
```

to fix this, but in NodeJS, global (the window equivalent here), does not have User, since I import is as a variable. Is it possible to mock the constructor to give me something with a mocked save()? I've also taken a look at an npm module called [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire), but I was hoping I could do this without mocking and replacing the entire user module in my handler.

Comment: there isn't enough information here, post your actual code and test

Comment: @user2943490 I've since added some code and test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not solve the issue of mocking a local variable, but it will solve the issue of unit testing the creation of new documents.

When creating a new document, it is better to use Model.create(). This can be mocked effectively, and it is simply less code. The right way to handle this and test it would be:

```
var User = import('User.js')

post: function(req, res) {
  User.create({
      password    : req.body.password,
      email       : req.body.email,
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      ....
    } else {
      ....
    }
  });
});
```

Corresponding test:

```
var Hander = require('user.js')

it('works properly', function() {
  spyOn(User, 'create').andReturn(null)
  Handler.post(req, res);
});
```

Hopefully this workaround will help other people getting frustrated with jasmine and mongoose unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can only swap a function with a spy after the object is created. Hence this will work:

```
var user = new User(…);
spyOn(user, save).…;
doSomething();
```

where this will not:

```
spyOn(User, save).…
doSomething()
```

Of course you could change the function inside mongoose that creates the save function on the object… but you probably don't want to go there.

Answer (score 0):

In a sane world, you would be able to do this.

`spyOn(Model.prototype, 'save')`

However, Mongoose tries to overload all their Model functions to work as node.js callbacks and Promises simultaneously. To do this, they manipulate the prototype in a way that is a little hard to predict without reading the actual Model code (https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js).

Here's an example that actually worked for me.

`spyOn(Model.prototype, '$__save').and.callFake(function (options, callback) {
   callback();
});`

For the record, I am using Mongoose with Promises in the application code.